# How to find list of triggers that are existed on a table. I am using sybase ASE 15-2

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How to find list of triggers that are existed in a table. I am using sybase ASE 15-2

I tried

```
exec sp_depends 'dbo.mytable'
```

I am getting errors..

Comment: Triggers are listed in sysobjects.type = "TR".  I can't remember the join field though..otherwise I would give you a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- check that sp_depends exists:

```
use sybsystemprocs    
go
sp_help sp_depends
go
```

2- check that your version of sp_depends in installmaster corresponds to your ASE version

```
use master
go
sp_version  -- look at the version of installmasater
go
select @@version  -- look at the version of ASE
go
-- if it is not the same version, run installmaster script (check in TEST first)
```

2- run the commands:

```
use <dbname>
go
exec sp_depends 'mytable'  OR sp_depends mytable
go
```

Comment: I executed the 1) part  @Vince                        
The command completed with no results returned                        
                           
Name Owner Object_type                
sp_depends dbo stored procedure                      
                           
Data_located_on_segment When_created                    
not applicable 4/2/2012 12:30:26.816 PM                    
                           
Parameter_name Type Length Prec Scale Param_order Mode
 objname varchar 92 [NULL] [NULL] 1 in
 column_name varchar 30 [NULL] [NULL] 2 in